# Sculpt Mask Not Working`

Tags: sculpt, sculpt-mode

I'm using Blender 2.93.3. Trying to create a mask while using the sculpting tools. No method of applying a mask produces a visible result, and masking is not taking place. I've tried all suggestions found here and elsewhere - view overlays have mask turned on, for example, and suggestions for using ctrl/alt/shift keys do nothing. Other sculpt tools like draw, inflate, and so on work fine. Dyntopo mode is on; masking still does not work after dyntopo has created new mesh. This is on a plain vanilla starter file with the cube; cannot place mask on cube, but I can perform other sculpting actions.

Comment: maybe your Strength is at 0?

Comment: 0.5; also tried at 1, no joy.

Comment: maybe share a file? https://pasteall.org/blend/